# Git is Ignoring Configured Values

Tags: git, push-notification, githooks

I'd been using git 1.7.1 on a CentOS 6-based box but I needed to update to 1.7.12.4. To do this I had to compile and install from source, which went without a (reported) hitch.

However, now whenever I push anything I get the following error:

```
remote: *** hooks.mailinglist is not set so no email will be sent
```

This is strange, because the server's /etc/gitconfig has:

```
[hooks]
    mailinglist = foo@bar.com
```

but when I did `git config --global --list`, it didn't show up.

I added it manually via `git config --global hooks.mailinglist "foo@bar.com"` and now it shows up when I do `git config --global --list`:

```
hooks.mailinglist=foo@bar.com
```

but pushes still get the same error: `remote: *** hooks.mailinglist is not set so no email will be sent`

Is my system-wide configuration being overridden somewhere?

**Edit**

If I create a symlink from the server's git user's `~/.gitconfig` to `/etc/gitconfig`, things behave as expected. But I'm still unsure as to why the global/system settings are being ignored.

Comment: Did you run those commands on the server?

Comment: Everything except the pushes was run from the server.

Comment: This sounds like a configuration error: that the new Git is using a different global config path (vs the old Git), and both new and old Git versions exist (perhaps the old one only partially) and when run manually you get the new one but when run via ssh you get the old one.

Comment: `whereis git` only returns paths to the new one. I also did a `find / -type f -name git` on the system and then ran `git --version` on each of those binaries; all of them returned 1.7.12.4. I don't necessarily disagree with your assessment, but if it's true, I'm at a loss as to explain how.